# Underscore templates not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, underscore.js

I can't figure out why my template wont work in IE (Any version)

Template

```
<div id="Hero-Right">
<script type="text/html" id="heroItems">                        
      {{ _.each( planet.heroItems, function( heroItem ){ }}
      <div class="item first">
           img src="{{= heroItem.image }}" />
           <div class="item-text">
                {{= heroItem.text }}
           </div>
      </div>
      {{ }); }}
 </script>
 </div>
```

My data is

```
var data = {
        heroItems: [
            {
                image: "Images/Top-TV.png",
                text: "Watch the Tv Show"
            },
            {
                image: "Images/Top-Broc.png",
                text: "The Brand"
            }
        ]
     }
```

To render the template I call the function

```
function renderTemplate(data) {
    var template = _.template(
             $("#heroItems").html()
         );
    $("#Hero-Right").html(
            template(data)
        );
};
```

To use moustache delimiter i changed the underscore delimeters using

```
 _.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
};
```

This shows up fine in chrome.

Comment: Well what *does* happen in IE? Do you see errors in the developer console?

Comment: where is the variable `planet` coming for? can you post a complete jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I see no errors in IE.

Comment: OK so is it that makes you say it doesn't work? Can you not imagine why that information would be useful to someone trying to help fix the problem?

Comment: You have a typo in the template, missing the `<` with the image tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are running an older IE version. In that case:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,     <-- Trailing Comma
};
```

Remove the Trailing Comma

Comment: impressive. eagle eye :) (And that that would cause errors in IE, at least in those versions susceptible to the problem, right?)

Comment: This would surely cause some issues for older IE browsers so thanks for this. My issue was that the code was beingh executed before underscore loaded. Not sure why IE didn't show anything in console. Anyway, once I put the code in an doc.ready function it worked perfect.